# How to end editing QTableWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I need to finish edit QTableWidget when some event happend.

```
MyWindow::onSomeEvent
{
  // Finish ui->table editing
  //...
}
```

How can I do this?

---

The event is a spinbox editing. When it happend rows count becomes equled its value.

I tried to send enter key press event. But when editing item in the last row and new rows count is less then current it does not work.

```
QKeyEvent *ev = new  QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease,
                               Qt::Key_Return,
                               Qt::NoModifier);

QApplication::sendEvent(ui->table, ev);
ui->table->setRowCount(value);
QApplication::sendEvent(ui->table, ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyWindow::onSomeEvent()
{
    QKeyEvent *ev = new  QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease,Qt::Key_Return,Qt::NoModifier);
    QApplication::sendEvent(ui->tableWidget,ev);
}
```

You just emulate `Enter` pressing when something happens.

Comment: I don't want to make table not editable. I want to finish enter new value to editing cell at that moment like I pressed enter key.

Comment: @Ufx Sorry, but I understood, see my edit, I test it, works normal.

Comment: @Ufx it works, but setRowCount in your case delete a few or one last row/rows, current cell loses focus and your enter pressing catch tableWidget, not a cell.